# Execute an SQL Query and redirect after successfull execution using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a button (id="deleteAccount"). If the user clicks on it, I want them to be logged out and delete their account from the database and then redirect to the site's homepage. I'm using SESSION to identify the user.

**Right now, I'm able to only delete their data from the but not log them out and redirect them to the homepage.**

Here's my *deleteUserAccount.php*

```
<?php session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"]))
{
        header("Location:blocked.php");
        $_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
}
?>

<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "database";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $user = $_SESSION["username"];

    $deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM `users` WHERE Username='$user'";
    $deleteQuery = $conn->query($deleteSQL);

    if($deleteQuery) {
        unset($_SESSION["username"]);
        unset($_SESSION["password"]);
        header("Location:index.php");
    }
    else {
        echo "error";
    }

?>
```

And here's my JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#deleteAccount').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'deleteUserAccount.php'
        });
    });

});
```

THANKS

Comment: you're mixing server-side and client-side here. As you do an ajax-call the `header()` in php is kinda useless. You'd need to redirect in javasacript, in the success-callback of your ajax.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for pointing it out. I'm new to AJAX. In fact this is the first time I'm using AJAX. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'deleteUserAccount.php',
            success : function() {
                $(location).attr('href', 'yoursite/index.php')
            }
        });
```

You are doing an ajax call here and you redirect user using php thats why user not redirect to the home page. You need to do with client side script in your ajax success callback.

Comment: some sort of explanation would be helpful I guess.